# Does the compression tag refer to dynamics processing or data reduction?

Tags: discussion, tags

So when I was going updating the tag wikis for the tags without good descriptions, I noticed that the `compression` tag is used almost equally to refer to the dynamic compression of audio and to refer to file compression algorithms such as MP3.

According to my count of the questions [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression), the count stands at 22 uses for dynamics and 17 for data.

Is this something we want to manage at this stage in the site's life, or is it fine to have the same tag refer to such different things?
Also, if we decide a single tag is fine, how do we reflect this in the tag wiki?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, when I think "compression" in a studio production context, I immediately think of dynamic range compression for audio. Filesize compression via audio/video codecs *is* relevant to the site's audience, but I think it should have a separate tag. As always though, I'm interested to hear from the community.

Comment: We probably should call it "Audio Compression" to clarify.

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge I like where you're going with that. Perhaps we strike "compression" entirely and go with two tags, to the effect of filesize-compression and dynamic-range-compression? I think we can come up with better names than those, but they're just for example.

Comment: I agree.  That should get rid of the confusion.

Comment: I would go with data-compression and audio-compression. Simple enough to pick which one is applicable without much experience, but different enough that someone answering can filter better.

Comment: I would prefer compression-data and compression-dynamic (or compression-dynamics). "Audio Compression" feels ambiguous to someone coming from an IT background, even if it is natural in the audio world.

Comment: I like having compression as the first part of the tag, and I feel like those two would perfectly suit our needs right now.

Comment: +1 on compression-data and compression-dynamic ... i think whatever way it's worded it needs to play well with the auto-complete, that's the main thing to prevent future problems

Answer (score 0):

I just submitted a wiki excerpt for [compression].  Of course it was after the fact that I ran into this question, as I was going to ask something similar, so it may be a useless excerpt as it stands.

So, just to add to the suggestions here, <strike>what about [audio-compression] and [video-compression].  The former would strike me as dynamics.  The later as data, though obviously particular to video (maybe that's not ideal).</strike>  There could be a third more generic, [data-compression].  **I think I've changed my mind... comments below.**

I guess the video oriented tag made sense to me as I was writing the excerpt because of the scope of the site itself.  If it's not used, or useful by itself, then...

Comment: `what about [audio-compression] and [video-compression]. The former would strike me as dynamics. The later as data, ` ... audio files can be compressed too eg mp3 ... aren't you leaving that out ... I know it's covered by mp3 and ogg etc but still?

Comment: @byronyasgur, yep... after rereading, I think the OP got it right in the question. There is [compression-dynamic] and [compression-data]. I think that probably covers it all